# Do Dark Sectors count as missions for resource extractors

Tags: warframe

In order to deploy a Resource Extractor at a planet, you must complete all missions on a planet.

Does this include the player-taxed Dark Sector missions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Since it is not mandatory to complete Dark Sector missions to officially have 'completed' a planet, you can safely ignore them if your only goal is to have resource extractors on said planet.

I base this answer upon the fact that you must only complete all *normal* nodes on a planet to be able to access that planet's Nightmare Mode mission.

Comment: I completed the last non-Dark Sector missions on Venus that I needed and noticed both the resource extractor option and Nightmare Mode mission were available.